# Sanitize Data and encrypt password

Tags: php

```
$data   = Core::SanitizeData($data);
Core::Encrypt($currPaswd)
```

Can someone explain me these statements. What does these statements help us to do

```
SELECT email
FROM   mobile_users
WHERE  id='".$userId."' AND password='".Core::Encrypt($currPaswd)."'";

global $_error;
$data   = Core::SanitizeData($data);
$status = '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Breakdown of statements**

```
$data = Core::SanitizeData($data);
```

- `$data =` is the variable where the result is being stored.
- `Core` is the class, from which a function needs to be called.
- `::`  is the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) which identifies the scope from which the thing has to be considered.
- `SanitizeData` is the [function](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpfunctions.php), identified by opening `(` and closing `)` which is being called.
- `($data)` is the variable which is being passed to the function as [argument or parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Similarly for `Core::Encrypt($currPaswd)`

**What exactly are these functions doing?**

*In general*

That can be confirmed from reading and understanding their function definition, or if some [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php) are provided in the code near the top of function definition (though comments tend to not be maintained, and thus can misguide).

*For your current question*

Guessing from the function names, it appears `SanitizeData()` [sanitizes (user input) data](http://diovo.com/2008/09/sanitizing-user-data-how-and-where-to-do-it/), and `Encrypt()` [encrypts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) the passed string, which seems to be the current passed (`$currPaswd`).